# Secure way to check subfolder with pathlib

Tags: security, python-3.x

The python3 series recently added an object-oriented path manipulation library called pathlib.   I'd like to be able to assert that a child file is a descendant of a parent to avoid people reading /etc/passwd and the like.  The standard library doesn't offer any advice on using pathlib securely.  Can someone offer some best practices for using pathlib securely?

Currently, I'm doing something like this.  `root` is a pathlib object that is the parent folder.  `path` is a string of a path supposedly relative to a root.  However, it's from user input and can not be trusted.

```
try:
    root = root.resolve()
except (FileNotFoundError, RuntimeError):
    raise Exception('your root directory does not exist')

path_obj = root / path
try:
    path_obj = path_obj.resolve()
except (FileNotFoundError, RuntimeError):
    raise Exception('your local file does not exist')

if root not in path_obj.parents:
    raise Exception('nice try')
```

Super-pedantic note: in practice I raise the exact same kind of exception for all three as to not leak the existence/non-existence of files.

Comment: an attacker may create a symlink *after* you've called `path_obj.resolve()`

Answer (score -1):

Your codes are OKAY to prevent your application against Local File Inclusion or Directory Traversal attacks but there is a bug.

Also you can check out Django source code of static file server to be sure about your code algorithm. https://github.com/django/django/blob/cb2c3ce15443a0666646e8b60984830c38d3ecde/django/views/static.py

Comment: When you say "but there is a bug" do you mean the symlink race mentioned by JF Sebastian or something else?